# Vue with TypeScript: How to access component properties in type safe way

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am new to Vue's setup API and one thing still eludes me: I need access to properties of a child component from a parent component. It works fine, but I cant get the typescript definition right. I always get the TS error, that the propery does not exist. And from TypeScript perspective it seems to be correct, as there is no property in the object I defined. But there must be a way to make TS understand.

```
<template>
  <child ref="child" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Child from 'child.vue'

export default {
  name: 'parent',
  mounted() {
    const child: Child = this.$refs.child;
    console.log(child.myprop); // TS2339: Property 'myprop' does not exist on type...
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'child',
  setup(props, context) {
    const myprop = 1;
    context.expose({myprop});
    return {myprop};
  }
})
</script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const child: InstanceType<typeof Child> = this.$refs.child;
```

or this:

```
const child = this.$refs.child as Child;
```

Comment: ``as Child`` makes no difference. The ``InstanceType<typeof Child>`` gives another error: TS2339: Property 'myprop' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 4 more ..., {}>'.

Comment: @Reynicke What about `as InstanceType<typeof Child>`? Would make sense here. The use of `Child` alone is incorrect as it's a component, not comp instance

Comment: ``InstanceType<typeof Child>`` is the answer and works fine, if I remove the typo I had in the import statement ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Composition API and Options API here.

if you rewrite the parent component to use Composition API, working with types would be easier:

```js
import Child from 'child.vue'
    
export default {
  name: 'parent',
  setup() {
    const childRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof Child>>();

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(childRef.value?.myProp);
    })

    return { childRef };
  }
}
```